# Application of Arzela Ascoli theorem?

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega$ an open bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider $u_k: \Omega \to \mathbb R , k=1,2,...$ a sequence of functions. Suppose that $|u_k(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$. Suppose that for each ball $B$ with $\overline{B} \subset \Omega$ we have

$$|u_k (x) - u_k(y)| \leq C(B) |x-y| , \forall k \geq 1 $$
and for all $x,y \in B.$

My question is: there is a subsequence $u_{k_j}$ and a function $u : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that

$$ \lim_{j \to + \infty}  u_{k_j} (x) = u(x) ,$$
for all $x \in \Omega$? I think that is possible to prove this using Arzela Ascoli theorem and a diagonal argument. But I dont know how to prove or give an counterexample... Someone could help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: It is true. Exhaust $\Omega$ with compacts, apply on these Arzela Ascoli, and a diagonal argument yields the subsequence.

Comment: You also do not need the boundedness; this works with all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by exactly the argument that @user251257 suggested.